# Converting array of objects and nested array to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, api

I have an API endpoint that expects the following json string (this is an example).

```
{
    "userid": "1234",
    "bookshelf": "3",
    "bookcount": "6",
    "books":[
        {"bookid": "1"},
        {"bookid": "2"},
        {"bookid": "3"},
        {"bookid": "6"}
]}
```

The api accesses each in the following manner:

```
$userid = $data['userid'];
$bookshelf = $data['bookshelf'];
```

etc...
I can also loop through the books and get each bookid with:

```
$data['books'][$i]['bookid']
```

When I send the above json string via a tool like postman it works fine. I'm having trouble manufacturing this same json string on the javascript side. This is how I populate the data on the front end of my site.

```
var data = new Array();
data.push({ "userid": "1234" });
data.push({ "bookshelf": "3" });
data.push({ "bookcount": "6" });
data.push({ "books": selectedbooks }); // This is an array of bookid objects
```

The problem is whether I json.stringify it and send to the webserver and over to the api or have the webserver json_encode, I end up with numeric indexes that can only be accessed like `$data[0]['userid'];` once it's decoded by the api, which differs from how the api is working. This would require the json string to be assembled in an exact sequence if the api supported it.

How do I go about getting this data in the required format?

Comment: Create an object and set properties to it  and then push this object to `data`

Comment: Learn about data structures in JavaScript: http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html

Comment: Thanks to all for the help. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numeric indexes are coming because you're preparing the data as an array, not an object. Arrays in JavaScript are indexed, not associative. Try:

```
var data = {
    userid: 1234,
    bookshelf: 3,
    bookcount: 6,
    books: selectedbooks
};
```

Comment: Dude your everywhere. How many tabs have you opened? have mercy on your RAM

Comment: Ha. What can I say. Love helpin'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object, not an array.

```
var data = {};
data["userid"] = "1234";
data["bookshelf"] = "3";
data["bookcount"] = "6";
data["books"] = selectedbooks; // This is an array of bookid objects
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not supposed to be an array, it's an object. The only array is in the `books` property.

```
var data = {}
data.userid = "1234";
data.bookshelf = "3";
data.bookcount = "6";
data.books = selectedbooks;
```

or more succintly:

```
var data = {
    userid: "1234",
    bookshelf: "3",
    bookcount: 6,
    books: selectedbooks
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily transform your array into the expected object :

```
var arr = [
    {"userid": "1234"},
    {"bookshelf": "3"},
    {"bookcount": "6"},
    {
       "books":[
         {"bookid": "1"},
         {"bookid": "2"},
         {"bookid": "3"},
         {"bookid": "6"}
    ]}
];
var obj = {} ;
arr.forEach(item => {
  var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  obj[key] = item[key];
});
console.log(obj); 
//{ userid: '1234',
//  bookshelf: '3',
//  bookcount: '6',
//  books: 
//   [ { bookid: '1' },
//     { bookid: '2' },
//     { bookid: '3' },
//     { bookid: '6' } ] }
```